# Trying to style SwingNodes in JavaFX with GTKLookAndFeel freezes application

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gtk, look-and-feel

We have a Java application that used Swing, but we are migrating it to JavaFX. Therefore, we wrap the old Swing code into `SwingNode`s and replace them step-by-step.

Before migrating, the Swing application used `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel` as look-and-feel (default on Ubuntu). We used following code to set it (if available):

```
for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
  if (info.getClassName().equals("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel")) {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
  }
}
```

This worked fine. Yet, after switching to JavaFX, the call to `UIManager.setLookAndFeel()` freezes the application, and nothing happens. The manual setting of the look-and-feel is needed since we want to still style the Swing components that have not been migrated to JavaFX based on the `GTKLookAndFeel`.

*Further info: This only does not work with `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel`, since it works when using `javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel`, `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel` or `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel`.*

What can we do to make it work with `GTKLookAndFeel` to style our Swing components in the `SwingNode`s?

Comment: Are you doing it in the correct thread?  Swing code needs to be run inside [EventQueue.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: @VGR: Didn't do that before, changed it now, but still does not change the behavior. Still freezes the application.

Comment: Try running it on the command line, and dumping all thread stacks.  On Windows, this is done with Ctrl-Break;  on other systems, SIGQUIT will do it, accomplished with Ctrl-\ or a separate `kill -3` command.  One of the stack traces should indicate where setLookAndFeel is stuck.

Comment: @VGR: The thread that is running the look-and-feel setting seems to be stuck at `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKEngine.native_get_gtk_setting(Native Method)`... Tested this with a thread dump and the eclipse debugger.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample? I'm running this snippet https://pastebin.com/wnLFqD6i on Xfce with the latest GTK and Java 8 u121, it runs fine. Looking at native_get_gtk_setting‌, there's a synchronize block, seems suspicious. By the way, have you tried -Dswing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel?

Comment: @AndreLDM: Okay, your example also works on my machine.
We have a `JTabbedPane` that gets set as a SwingNode's content in our view's controller's `initialize` method, and we are currently investigating if it has something to do with that. It seems that the constructor call of `JTabbedPane` hangs the application. I will try to create a minimal example.

Comment: You can also provide a thread dump with `jstack -l`, it will show you if there is a deadlock. You guys mentioned that the thread was stuck in `native_get_gtk_setting‌​`, and that this method is synchronized, so maybe another thread is holding the lock. And that might happen because Swing and JavaFX each have their own thread...

Comment: Is the installed version of GTK >=2.2? I know this is an old question, just wanted to find out if you found a solution to this issue.

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD: I have access to the PC again tomorrow, then I can check. I know the OS is a default `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` install.

Comment: @ChetanJadhavCD `dpkg -s libgtk2.0-0|grep '^Version'` returns `Version: 2.24.30-1ubuntu1.16.04.2` and `dpkg -s libgtk-3-0|grep '^Version'` returns `Version: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3`

Comment: Sorry @MarkusWeninger that was the only thing I had in mind that I could suggest, I dunno what else to try at this point.

Comment: I came across similar scenario with only the swing components and I think this is a problem with the `GKT` deadlocking. These posts https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341538 and https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341799 helped me solve the issue by calling `gdk_threads_leave()` before Swing/AWT dispatches the threads.

Comment: @hari Thank you for your help. In the meantime since I asked this question we ported all SwingNodes. If I find the time, I will set up an example application to test it.

Comment: Also: shouldn't there be a `break` statement in your if ?

Answer (score 1):

Gui components need to be updated into gui threads.

Try one of the following:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
//commands
});

javafx.application.Platform.runLater(() -> {
//commands
});
```

Comment: Tried both before, and both do not resolve the problem.